# angularjs passing in css file to header in IE

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am currently trying to pass a css file to a iframe.  I got the css to work correctly in Chrome but not in IE.  When trying to add it to the header, it translate the value directly and not the angular text.  It changes the {{}} into the url without converting it.

Example:

```
<head>
    <link href="{{css}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

In Chrome comes out as

> http://localhost/Content/css/themes/everyday/Layout.css

In IE

> /%7B%7Bcss%7D%7D

Is there a way to convert it in angular to embed the css correctly.

Comment: did you tried `ng-attr-href="{{css}}"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pankaj Parkar put me on the right track with this one.  The href needed to be handled as angular ng-href to smooth out the special characters.

Here is the correct answer:

```
<link ng-href="{{css}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```